# pyQt5 segfault when using QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, python-3.x, segmentation-fault, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I am consistently getting a segfault (11) when using the QSortFilterProxy with PyQT5 and python3 on my mac.

The table comes up as expected, and is able to sort just fine.
However, when an item is added, and then a subsequent sort is attempted, the gui crashes with "segfault 11"

My research hasn't been fruitful. I'm hoping someone here can help.
The following code is a simplistic example.

```
#! /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication,
                             QTableView, QWidget,QPushButton,
                             QVBoxLayout,QMainWindow)

import sys

class MyModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel) :
   def __init__(self,data=None,parent = None, *args) :
      super(MyModel,self).__init__(parent,*args) 
      
      self.data = data or []
     
   #Add item to the data. 
   def addItem(self,item) :
        
      #add the item to to the model data.
      self.data.append(item)
     
      #Emit signal to the TableView to redraw
      self.layoutChanged.emit()
        
   #Overloaded function that must be defined.      
   def data(self,index,role) :
      #The index (contains both x,y) and role are passed.  
      #The roles give instructions about how to display the model.
      row = index.row()
      col = index.column()
      
      #Insert the appropriate information into the display, based
      #on the column. 
      if role == Qt.DisplayRole :
         item = self.data[row]         
         if (col == 0) :
            return(item.name)
         if (col == 1) :  
            return(item.num)
  
   #rowCount must be overloaded
   def rowCount(self,index) :
      return(len(self.data))
   
   #columnCount must be overloaded
   def columnCount(self,index) :      
      return(2)
   
   #Display headers for the columns
   def headerData(self,section,orientation,role) :
      if (role != Qt.DisplayRole) :
         return
      if (orientation != Qt.Horizontal) :
         return      
      if (section == 0) :
         return("Name")
      if (section == 1) :
         return("Number")
      

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow) :
   def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs) :
      super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
      
      self.data = [] 
 
      proxymodel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
      proxymodel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
      proxymodel.setFilterKeyColumn(0)
      self.proxymodel = proxymodel
      
      #Create the TableView widget that will display the model
      self.mytable = QtWidgets.QTableView()
      self.mytable.setSortingEnabled(True)
           
      #Create the model that will be displayed in the table
      self.mymodel = MyModel(self.data)
      #Assign the model to the table
      self.mytable.setModel(proxymodel)
      
      self.proxymodel.setSourceModel(self.mymodel)
      #Put the table in the main widget's layout.
      #Need to have a layout for its size hint.
      layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
      layout.addWidget(self.mytable,0,Qt.AlignHCenter)
      
      button = QPushButton("Add Item",self)
      button.clicked.connect(self.addItem) 
      layout.addWidget(button)
      
      self.layout = layout
      
      #The actual widget. 
      widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
      widget.setLayout(layout)                    
      
      #Show the results
      self.setCentralWidget(widget)
      self.show()
      
      for i in range(10) :
         item = Item(i)
         self.mymodel.addItem(item)
         
   def addItem(self) :
      num = len(self.mymodel.data)
      item = Item(num)
      self.mymodel.addItem(item)
      
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the QSortFilterProxyModel but an incorrect implementation of the source model. On the other hand, although using layoutAboutToBeChanged solves the problem is not the appropriate option, as indicated in [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#inserting-and-removing-rows) if you want to add rows to the model then you must use the `beginInsertRows()` and `endInsertRows()` methods that will internally invoke the layoutAboutToBeChanged signal, considering the above, the most appropriate implementation is :

```
class MyModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data=None, parent=None, *args):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent, *args)

        self.data = data or []

    # Add item to the data.
    def addItem(self, item):
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), self.rowCount(), self.rowCount())
        self.data.append(item)
        self.endInsertRows()

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()
        if (row < 0 or row >= self.rowCount()) and (
            col < 0 or col >= self.columnCount()
        ):
            return

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            item = self.data[row]
            if col == 0:
                return item.name
            if col == 1:
                return item.num

    def rowCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.data)

    def columnCount(self, index=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 2

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return
        if orientation != Qt.Horizontal:
            return
        if section == 0:
            return "Name"
        if section == 1:
            return "Number"
```

Answer (score 0):

Emit a "layoutAboutToBeChanged" signal when changing the table.

```
class MyModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel) :
   def __init__(self,data=None,parent = None, *args) :
      super(MyModel,self).__init__(parent,*args) 
      
      self.data = data or []

   #Add item to the data. 
   def addItem(self,item) :
        
      #add the item to to the model data.
      self.data.append(item)

      **#Emit signal to the TableView to redraw**
      self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()      
      self.layoutChanged.emit()
```